# How to prevent span to adjust its width at end of parent?

Tags: html, css

When I move the span to the right and it reaches the end of the parent (div) it adjusts its width to fit the parent.

I want the span to keep its width even outside it's parent.

I also have line breaks (using '\n', because the text is passed by js, but not shown in codepen, for simplicity), so "white-space: nowrap" that would be the best aswers do not fit for me.

I made a code to illustrate the problem. In the code, if you change "left: 100px;" to "left: 200px;" the span breaks at the end of the parent.

```css
.bg {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  /*the text is shown in one line*/
  /*left: 200px; /*the text breaks in two lines*/
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #f00;
}

p {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <span class="text">
        <p>My text goes here.</p>
      </span>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/FelipeVR/pen/ZEvBvqy

Comment: Why are you using `position` here?

Comment: `white-space: nowrap`?

Comment: Also `span`s should not have block level elements like `p` as direct children.

Comment: try removing position and/or making it relative

Comment: Did you want the span to poke out from the div, or should the div hide the overflowed portion of the span?

Comment: @pavel You have to write a answer and not a comment. Because that would be a good solution!

Comment: @pavel, it is the solution. I tried to edit the question before someone gave me this, because I also want to break lines when i add a line break (\n, because I'm passing the text with js)

Comment: @SecurityObscurity, I can not remove position, because it is used in the original code, the codepen is just a simplification.

Comment: For handling line breaks, convert `.replace(/\\n/g, '<br>')` to br's

Comment: why not use `right: 0;` instead of `left: ypx;`?

Comment: @webketje, i'm using React, so it consider 'dangerous' uses tag inside text.

Comment: @Sana Mumtaz, this position will be translated (also animated) using left as reference

Comment: @pavel, following your ideia, I used 'white-space: pre' and it worked for my case. If you create an answer with both cases I will accept it as correct. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: @Felipe Please use sound judgment. Setting innerHTML is *not* dangerous in most cases, even if the React devs thought it would be smart to name it `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`. It is only dangerous if the text is **unsanitized user input**.

Comment: @Felipe It's nothing special which should be here as an answer. Glad to help you.